# How to recover deleted email attachments from iCloud

Tags: time-machine, mail.app, imap

This scenario sounds simple.
Receive mail on phone, delete all [because I don't keep any emails on my phone long term], then realise one of the emails was on IMAP. Try to get back that one mail from iCloud. All the others are POP & will be safely on my Mac so there's no need to keep duplicates on the phone.

Go into deleted & send it back to the Inbox, easy.
Check the Inbox… the attachment is 0KB.

Check on the Mac. The email was IMAP so of course it's been deleted there too.

Select the iCloud Inbox, then invoke Time Machine. Go back to a time the email was there.
Recover.
Mail says 'Recovering', then goes back to an empty inbox.
Rinse & repeat until infuriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution by accident, whilst testing something else.

Quit Mail. Reboot the Mac. Launch Mail.
Check the sidebar. There is now a new item, `com.apple.Mail.Backup.`
Inside there are all your recovery attempts.
Email & attachment successfully recovered & manually moved to a safe folder 'On My Mac'.

[image]

Now I can delete the recovered folders safely… well, maybe eventually after another restart. Right now they don't want to go anywhere. Contents deleted but folders still there.

In fact, several restarts & a rename later I managed to get rid of one folder, but the others are being somewhat tenacious. I guess I can live with that.

[image]

For users previously unaware of my despise for IMAP, this is one of the reasons I avoid using it. Deleting on one device deletes all copies. This, imnsho, is the most idiotic behaviour ever devised. YMMV.